# Primefaces changes from version 2.2.1 to 3.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I am working on integrating online whiteboard project, where the source code is found  [here](http://code.google.com/p/online-whiteboard/). It is originally written for primefaces version 2.2.1 but we want to integrate with our main application which using  latest primefaces version 3.4. After changing to latest version, we get lot of javascript errors and few of them are pasted below. 
What we need to look for if we have to upgrade from version 2.2.1 to 3.4 of primefaces?

## Errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' whiteboard.js.jsf:67
Uncaught ReferenceError: whiteboardDesigner is not defined :8080/emyed-whiteboard/whiteboard/workplace/fc4b4afe-f96f-442b-a0d0-bb29a46836dc/9fb61421-8c0f-4cbb-b0f7-96dc5e31bd56/:73
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/css: "http://localhost:8080/emyed-whiteboard/javax.faces.resource/whiteboard.css.jsf?ln=css". jquery.js.jsf:14
Uncaught ReferenceError: whiteboardDesigner is not defined :8080/emyed-whiteboard/whiteboard/workplace/fc4b4afe-f96f-442b-a0d0-bb29a46836dc/9fb61421-8c0f-4cbb-b0f7-96dc5e31bd56/:82
```

As per above errors, whiteboardDesigner is not defined. But it is already defined in one of the javascript.

Html pages where it get errors

```
  <button type="button" title="Draw Free Line" onclick="whiteboardDesigner.switchToMode('freeLineMode', 'pointer')" class="toolboxItem ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" value="Draw Free Line">
Uncaught ReferenceError: whiteboardDesigner is not defined
```

Javascript

```
// create a global whiteboard designer instance
whiteboardDesigner = new WhiteboardDesigner(new WhiteboardConfig(), whiteboardId, user, pubSubUrl, pubSubTransport);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that, we have included jQuery libraries in the resource directory. Below two actions where taken to resolve the issue.

```
1.Since primefaces 3.4 comes with latest version of jQuery library, we have removed the library which we added in the resource dir. This have resolved the issue. 
2. Added jQuery-UI to the resource dir for dialog function to work
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the [PrimeFaces blog](http://blog.primefaces.org/), PrimeFaces keeps a [migration guide on their Google code site](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide).

I'm a bit worried to see code you posted. It looks like Java, not JavaScript. (I'm not a JavaScript expert though.)